# Spark staging directory race condition when writing to hive partition?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am seeing intermittent exceptions when attempting to write a Dataset to a partition in a hive table.

`Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: /user/hive/warehouse/devl_fr9.db/fr9_ftdelivery_cpy_2_4d8eebd3_9691_47ce_8acc_b2a5123dabf6/.spark-staging-d996755c-eb81-4362-a393-31e8387104f0/date_id=20180604/part-00000-d996755c-eb81-4362-a393-31e8387104f0.c000.snappy.parquet for client 10.56.219.20 already exists`

If I check HDFS the relevant path does not exist. I can only assume this is some race condition regarding temp staging files. I am using Spark 2.3

Comment: Did the issue got fixed? I am facing the same issue in my cluster when multiple jobs running and cluster is under heavy load.

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason for this issue is that, during a job's execution, a task started writing data to that file and failed.

When a task fails, the data that it had already written is [not deleted/purged](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27194) by Spark (confirmed at least in 2.3 and 2.4). Therefore, when a different executor attempts to re-execute the failed task it will attempt to write to a file with the same name, and you'll get a FileAlreadyExistsException.

In your case, the file that already exists is called part-**00000**-d996755c-eb81-4362-a393-31e8387104f0.c000, so it's likely that you have a log message in stderr indicating that task **00000** was lost due to failure, something like

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task **00000** in stage...
```

If you fix the reason for this failure - probably an OutOfMemoryError, if the issue is intermitent - the  FileAlreadyExistsException will likely be solved because the task will not fail and leave temporary files behind.